# i want java regex all matching index

Tags: java, regex

The person who is studying kmp algorithm.
I am wondering if the kmp algorithm is too difficult to replace with regex.
I do not like this result.
The results I want are 0 and 1.
And I wonder if the regex time complexity is O (n + m).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String t = "aaa";   
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aa");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
    ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (m.find()) ans.add(m.start());
    for (int i : ans)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

i want Result [0 1]
this Result [1]

Comment: You study, you do not like, you wonder, and you want. Can you please tell what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to use regex to get the results I want. i want result is [0 1]

Comment: Cool, I have updated my answer now. See if it works for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now, since I got what your question is,
this how you can get the indices.

```
public static void main(){
    String input = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(aaa))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        all.add(matcher.start());
    }
    System.out.println(all);
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

To get the array, just return `all`.

Comment: i want result is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...  25, 26, 27]

Comment: answer is wrong. The answer to your example should be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,... 25, 26, 27].

Comment: Oh, I am sorry @이재국. I have updated the answer. Please go through it.

Comment: wow thx!!! you awesome !